# Cannot implicitly convert type to 'string' error

Tags: c#

I am currently working with displaying a list of items. I have created a method `GetNextItem` that returns `obj1`. When I am calling the method from the `buttonClick` I get this following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'TreeFarm.Form1.fruit_trees' to 'string'.
```

Not sure why is doing such thing.

```
public items_list GetNextItem()
{
    items_list obj1 = this.current_item;
    if (obj1 != null)
    {
        current_item = current_item.next_item;
    }
    return obj1;
}

ListForItems mainlist = new ListForItems();
private void ShowNextItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    labelSpecificItem.Text = mainlist.GetNextItem();         
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `item_list` ?

Comment: it's saying an `items_list` cannot be implicitly converted to a string (`.Text = mainList.GetNextItem()` instead of `.Text = (String)mainlist.GetNextItem()` or `.Text = mainlist.GetNextItem().ToString()`)

Comment: Is there a component of `items_list` that you want to display? Return that from your `GetNextItem()` method instead of the whole object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to convert a value of type `items_list` in to a string (`.Text` is of `String` type). So, if this is one of your objects you can create an implicit cast operator or maybe try using `.ToString()` or explicitly casting it to a string using `(String)mainlist.GetNextItem()`.

if you desire this kind of assignment and `items_list` is one of your objects, I would suggest the following addition to that class:

```
public static implicit operator String(items_list itemslist)
{
    return /* however you want to portray itemslist as a string */;
}
```

Otherwise you're going to have to rely on `ToString()` getting it right.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have mentioned, you cannot cast your `items_list` object to a `string`. If there is a component of `items_list` that you want to appear in your label, then assign that instead of the whole object:

```
labelSpecificItem.Text = mainlist.GetNextItem().textYouWantToSee;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your items need to override the `ToString()` method, and then use that to convert them into strings.

Follow this pattern:

```
public class FruitTree 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
   // your code
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return string.Format("A {0} tree.", Name);
   }
}
// later in the click handler
{
    labelSpecificItem.Text = tree_item.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself, but that's because I forgot how it was done. 
This was my code before:

```
public static string MakeRequest(string GetCountry, string GetTime, string Server, string Database)
    {
        var filter = Builders<RequestAccess>.Filter;
        var getCountryfilter = filter.Eq(x => x.GetCountry, GetCountry);
        var getTimefilter = filter.Eq(x => x.GetTime, GetTime);
        var databasefilter = filter.Eq(x => x.Database, Database);
        var serverfilter = filter.Eq(x => x.Servers, Server);

        var makeRequest = RequestCollection.Find(filter.Or(getCountryfilter, getTimefilter, databasefilter, serverfilter)).ToList();

        return makeRequest;
    }
```

But the code below is the correct one :)

```
public static List<RequestAccess> MakeRequest(string GetCountry, string GetTime, string Server, string Database)
    {
        var filter = Builders<RequestAccess>.Filter;
        var getCountryfilter = filter.Eq(x => x.GetCountry, GetCountry);
        var getTimefilter = filter.Eq(x => x.GetTime, GetTime);
        var databasefilter = filter.Eq(x => x.Database, Database);
        var serverfilter = filter.Eq(x => x.Servers, Server);

        var makeRequest = RequestCollection.Find(filter.Or(getCountryfilter, getTimefilter, databasefilter, serverfilter)).ToList();

        return makeRequest;
    }
```

So that means if you're trying to make a list of something then dont use "string" in `public static ...` :)

Comment: Can you see `string` in OP's code? It's different issue

Comment: It's not an different issue.. He declares "Item_List" somewhere, and when he declares it, he have made a "string" otherwise it wouldn't give him that error

Comment: `labelSpecificItem.Text = mainlist.GetNextItem();` this line is the source of error, `Text` should be set to some `string` but `mainlist.GetNextItem();` returns item of type `TreeFarm.Form1.fruit_trees`