# Position of an item and 'Cannot implicitly convert type to string error'

Tags: c#

I am working with lists. I am now experimenting with determining the positions of items inside list: `first`, `next` and `last`. I have been able to determine the first and last position of items in my list through function `getPostion` and displaying the item name through a Label. Three buttons in my form: ShowFirstItem ShowNextItem and ShowLastItem show the corresponding item in a label. I am having problems for displaying the next item. I have special method for `next` called `GetNextTree`. When I am calling this method from inside `ShowNextItem` click I get this error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'TreeFarm.Form1.fruit_trees' to 'string'.` How can avoid this error and display the item currently pointed to?

```
namespace TreeFarm {
     public partial class Form1: Form {
         public Form1() {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         public class ListForTrees {


             public fruit_trees GetNextTree() {
                 //save currently pointed tree
                 fruit_trees tree = this.current_tree;
                 if (tree != null) {
                     //move current_tree to the next tree, to be returned next time
                     current_tree = current_tree.next_tree;
                     //return saved tree object
                 }
                 return tree;
             }

         }
         private void ShowNextItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
             //Show Next Item
             labelSpecificTree.Text = mainlist.GetNextTree();
         }

     }
```

Comment: That's way too much code for me. Can you trim it down to where the error is?

Comment: this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871118/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-to-string-error - same homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your `fruit_tree` to a string, and you may also want to consider the `null` case:

```
private void ShowNextItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Show Next Item
    fruit_trees nextTree = mainlist.GetNextTree();
    if (nextTree == null)
    {
        labelSpecificTree.Text = "No more trees!";
    }
    else
    {
        labelSpecificTree.Text = nextTree.ToString();
    }
}
```

EDIT: As MattSmith pointed out, perhaps you'd prefer to use `nextTree.GetTreeType` instead to match your other methods. It's up to you.

Comment: Or to match his other methods, he would use .GetTreeType rather than .ToString()

Comment: @MattSmith I saw that CodeLover1985 had overridden `ToString` so I figured that was the natural go-to output. EDIT: I added an edit, thanks for picking up on that.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair & MattSmith +1 Yes you are right. I will use `nextTree.GetTreeType`. Now i am getting this error when running and click button: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @CodeLover1985 WOOPS, I mixed up my `null` check :P I fixed my code (notice it's `nextTree == null` instead of `nextTree != null`)... it's been a looooong day.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yes long day, but no worries. I may have something wrong somewhere else. It is now displaying `No more trees!`. The list comes from an array `ax` so there should be items being displayed `next`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your GetNextTree() method returns a fruit_trees object, but you're trying to set that return value to a String (the Text property of labelSpecificTree) inside of ShowNextItem.  You'll need to do something like this instead:

```
private void ShowNextItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Show Next Item
    labelSpecificTree.Text = mainlist.GetNextTree().ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: +1. I am unsure why but Now I am getting this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Ah, then see Chris Sinclair's answer, because I believe you'll need a null check before calling ToString().